# Putting alternate elements of an array into a combobox

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a certain number of elements in an array(statsname).

they are in fact as follows

```
x[1] A_NAME
x[2] A_CATEGORY
x[3] ANOTHER_NAME
x[4] A_CATEGORY
```

I want the categories in a combobox.
I did

```
 int up =1; 
            foreach (string things in statsname)
            { 
                //if the stat name doesnot contains TIME
                //Only then we add it to the combobox.
                if ((Convert.ToString(things[up]) == "CurrentNumber") || (Convert.ToString(things[up]) == "TotalNumber"))
                {
                    tcomboBox1.Items.Add(things[up-1]);
                }
                up++;

                if (up != statsname.Count())
                {
                    tcomboBox1.Items.Add(things[up - 1]);
                }
            }
```

However I get an error saying

```
Array out of bound
```

Why is it so ?
Where Did I go wrong ?

Comment: because it didn't fulfill the condition and you are incrementing the index to much that it didn't even fall in array size. Kindly use break point to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** you are comapring the `character` with `String`, it will never become `true`.

**Solution :** if you just want to get all the `Categories` added in `array` at `odd` positions like 1,3,5..etc.,

you can get the odd value out from `array` and assign the value to `combobox`.

EDIT : if you want you can get Even value out from array and assign the value to `combobox`.

Try This:

```
string [] statsname=new string[]  {"A_NAME1","Cat1","A_NAME2","Cat2","A_NAME3","Cat3","A_NAME4","Cat4"};
for(int i=0;i<statsname.Length;i++)
        {
         if(i%2==0)
           tcomboBox1.Items.Add(statsname[i]);
        }
```

Comment: i need the items of the 0 ,2,4,6 position.How do I get them ?

Answer (score 1):

An [IndexOutOfRangeException](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexoutofrangeexception) has occurred. This happens in C# programs that use array types. This exception will typically occur when a statement tries to access an element at an index greater than the maximum allowable index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < type.Length; i++)
{
    form.comboBox1.Items.Add(type[i]);
}
```